# GNU parallel does not split work evenly

Tags: gnu-parallel

My understanding is that the -X option should distribute arguments evenly among the jobs. Yet, I get a very skewed distribution:

```bsh
user@host:/tmp/ptest$ count() {
>   echo $#
> }
user@host:/tmp/ptest$ export -f count

user@host:/tmp/ptest$ count *.jpg
5825
user@host:/tmp/ptest$ parallel -X count ::: *.jpg
5039
197
197
197
195
```

Interestingly enough, using only a subset of the files leads to an even distribution of parameters:

```bsh
user@host:/tmp/ptest$ count p129*.jpg
975
user@host:/tmp/ptest$ parallel -X count ::: p129*.jpg
244
244
244
243

user@host:/tmp/ptest$ count p12*.jpg
4007
user@host:/tmp/ptest$ parallel -X count ::: p12*.jpg
1002
1002
1002
1001

user@host:/tmp/ptest$ count p13*.jpg
1818
user@host:/tmp/ptest$ parallel -X count ::: p13*.jpg
455
455
455
453
```

Why is wrong in the first case and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-X` distributes evenly when it hits EOF.

So in your case it fills up the buffer for a full command line (5039 names) and starts that. It then reads another 800 names until it reaches EOF. That is not enough to start a full job, so these are distributed amongst the jobslots.

See page 37 https://zenodo.org/record/1146014

It is done this way to avoid having to read all jobs in advance, as all jobs may not be available (think `tail -f file.names | parallel ...`).

It might be a better idea, if GNU Parallel read enough names to fill up all jobslots before starting the next job in `-X`mode, so it could detect EOF earlier. This, however, has not been implemented. Patch welcome.

A workaround is to use:

```
ls *.jpg |
  parallel --round --pipe -N1 parallel -Xj1 count
```

It cannot output after each job, but it can do linebuffered output:

```
ls *.jpg |
  parallel --lb --round --pipe -N1 parallel --lb -Xj1 count
```

If the filenames contain \n:

```
printf '%s\0' *.jpg |
  parallel --recend '\0' --round --lb --pipe -N1 parallel -0Xj1 count
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining why this happens. Is there any way to achieve or approximate the desired behaviour?

Comment: The linked material looks like a great book by the way!